# Como manter alterações feitas pelo console do navegador?

Tags: javascript, console, lado-do-cliente

Oi, eu estava vendo o código de alguns sites na internet pelo console e fazendo algumas alterações para ver o que acontecia, e isso chegou a um ponto onde eu queria salvar todas essas alterações, mesmo que só para mim. (já que eu sei que no servidor do site isso é impossível...)

O problema é que quando eu recarrego o site, ele substitui o que eu editei pelo o que vêm do servidor (o que faz total sentido) mas dessa forma não há como saber como ele reagiria carregando aquele documento que eu editei.

Dito isso, vamos ao que interessa:

É possível atualizar um site de forma que ele carregue o código que eu editei ao invés do que vêm do servidor?

É possível carregar documentos javascript que eu tenho na minha maquina diretamente no site que eu estou acessando? (ou seja, uma técnica melhor que copiar tudo e colar tudo no console)

Agradeço a ajuda e relembro que eu só quero fazer essas alterações no site que recebi e que está no navegador, eu sei que teoricamente tudo o que eu falei é possível de se fazer (o que é um dos motivos para não confiar em nada client-side) mas não tenho a mínima ideia de como.

Comment: uma das soluções é você apontar o dominio desejado via arquivo HOSTS da sua máquina para outro servidor. Neste servidor você faria um bypass dos arquivos, alterando somente os desejados via programação - outra solução seria você fazer (ou encontrar) uma extensão para o seu navegador, que fizesse ou mantivesse as alterações localmente - extensões tem o poder de alterar conteúdos de qualquer site (localmente).

Comment: sim é chato fazer alterações e elas não serem salvas, mas pra sua sorte, é possível salvar essas alterações em formatos de
**"WORKSPACES"**, uma ferramenta usada no ***GOOGLE CHROME***, tem um vídeo bem explicativo, assista e compreenda essa função: > [CLIQUE AQUI E VEJA O VÍDEO!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpEs6fLnwO0) Boa sorte em seu projeto!